# How can I display a loading gif until an entire html page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that's pretty intensive via HTML and CSS, which leads to some elements loading faster then others when a user visits the page. The background may take awhile to load, and so on... It gets pretty ugly seeing it all load element by element...

So I'm wondering how I can first load a different page (page1, that has simply a gif and bare minimals of html) and then page2 (page with intensive html) will appear only after the client's browser has fetched all of the pages html.

I believe this can be done with JQuery, which I know almost nothing about...

Any advice would be appreciated,
Thanks,

Comment: You can use [Blockui](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/). that do all the work.

Comment: On page1 do `setTimeout(function() { window.location = 'page2.html' }, 10000);` that will solve it.

Comment: `<div id="loading">loading stuff here</div><div id="realbody"></div>`, then some jquery to `.load()` the real body content into #realbody and hide #loading when that's done.

Comment: If your page is taking that long to load because of the amount of HTML  and CSS on it, you may want to re-think what you're doing in the first place.

Comment: @Zarathuztra It's a matter of 1-4 seconds in reality, I just rather have it look like it's running a lot smoother.

Comment: You can just Lazyload the image.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the following HTML (at the top of the body is best):

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

And this CSS:

```css
#loading {
    background: url('spinner.gif') no-repeat center center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

And the following JavaScript (uses jQuery):

```
function hideLoader() {
    $('#loading').hide();
}

$(window).ready(hideLoader);

// Strongly recommended: Hide loader after 20 seconds, even if the page hasn't finished loading
setTimeout(hideLoader, 20 * 1000);
```

You could put the styles inline on the `div` instead of in a stylesheet for less chance of a flash of content before the loader. Also, you could use https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/ or a similar tool to convert your GIF to a base 64 URI, and use that instead of `spinner.gif`.

Comment: @Shortland Well, you can't display a progress bar before loading the progress bar :)

Comment: @Cristy I posted the comment before he added the jQuery, deleted,

Comment: And thanks, this works great, Will look into base64 with images aswell.

Comment: Also Read: [How to Display Loading Image While Page Loads using jQuery](https://devnote.in/how-to-display-loading-image-while-page-loads-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 7):

```
    <div id="overlay"></div>
<style>
    #overlay {
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
     $('#overlay').addClass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is almost identical to the other answer

Comment: @Zarathuztra i never saw that.. just 2 mins gap.. probably we both were writing at the same time..

Answer (score 6):

I have implemented in Laravel and it worked as expected,

```
<style>
.loader {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            background-color: #ffffffcf;
        }
        .loader img{
            position: relative;
            left: 40%;
            top: 40%;
        }
</style>

<div class="loader" ><img src="{{asset('public/img/loader.gif')}}"></div>

<script>
    window.onload = function() 
    {
        //display loader on page load 
        $('.loader').fadeOut();
    }

</script>
```