# ajaxQueue loading icon

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the following code to queue ajax requests and not block actions on the page.
The problem is, I need to show a loading icon to indicate that the execution of the queue is not complete. I can't figure out how to do it, and everything I've tried just is closed immediately.

```
  // jQuery on an empty object, we are going to use this as our Queue
  var ajaxQueue = $jq({});

  $jq.ajaxQueue = function( ajaxOpts ) {
    var jqXHR,
        dfd = $jq.Deferred(),
        promise = dfd.promise();

    // queue our ajax request
    ajaxQueue.queue( doRequest );

    // add the abort method
    promise.abort = function( statusText ) {
        // proxy abort to the jqXHR if it is active
        if ( jqXHR ) {
            return jqXHR.abort( statusText );
        }
        // if there wasn't already a jqXHR we need to remove from queue
        var queue = ajaxQueue.queue(),
            index = $jq.inArray( doRequest, queue );

        if ( index > -1 ) {
            queue.splice( index, 1 );
        }
      // and then reject the deferred
      dfd.rejectWith( ajaxOpts.context || ajaxOpts,
            [ promise, statusText, "" ] );
      return promise;
    };

    // run the actual query
    function doRequest( next ) {
        jqXHR = $jq.ajax( ajaxOpts )
            .done( dfd.resolve )
            .fail( dfd.reject )
            .then( next, next );
    }
    return promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div on the page to hold your icon.
I would use a loading gif icon in this case.
When you first fire the ajax on the page use .show() to display it
then inside of your .done use .hide()

Similar to this post [How can I display a loading gif until an entire html page has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131821/how-can-i-display-a-loading-gif-until-an-entire-html-page-has-been-loaded)