# how to show load in progress for vis.js chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

For the first time to access vis.js timeline chart. A user's browser needs to download the vis.js library. It will take some time to show the chart. I am wondering how to display a message or animated image before the chart is fully loaded.

Once the chart is fully loaded, let the message or image fadeOut.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The option "animationPreload " should do the thing for you . See here http://visjs.org/docs/graph3d/

Comment: thanks! timeline chart seems does not have animationPreload option in the configuration   http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/

Comment: Indeed, this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use stabilization events as shown in this [example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/loadingBar.html) in vis.js documentation. It gives you an example how to implement a loading bar but you can use this mechanism to implement other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using the `onInitialDrawComplete` callback in the options for Timeline.

Show whatever loader mechanism you want and then swap it with the timeline once this fires.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something until the whole html is loaded, there is a solution here that can help you:
[How can I display a loading gif until an entire html page has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131821/how-can-i-display-a-loading-gif-until-an-entire-html-page-has-been-loaded)

I also use vis.js timeline in one of my projects and I'm using ajax to get data from the server into the timeline. For this kind of progress presentation I'm using an ajax loader, like this, it works perfectly:

**in the <head> section:**

```
<script>
$( function() {
    var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
    $(document)
      .ajaxStart(function () {
        $loading.show();
      })
      .ajaxStop(function () {
        $loading.hide();
      });
});
</script>
```

**in the <body> section:**

```
<div id="loadingDiv" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; position:fixed; left: 50%; margin-left:-150px; top:50%; margin-top:-200px; z-index:1000; opacity: 0.35; filter: alpha(opacity=35); ">
<img id="loading-image" src="./ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```